# How to fix malformed characters show up in tmux window from pressing specific keys?

Tags: tmux

[image]

On any tmux window, pressing keys such as "arrow up", and (only sometimes) "backspace", makes strange characters appear, such as the ones shown on the image.

In the case of arrow up (easiest and most consistent to reproduce), the characters show up instead of the previous used command.

Comment: Use of arrow keys for command history is a feature of the shell that is running *inside* the terminal. Have you configured tmux to use `/bin/bash`?

Comment: This is a default installation of tmux. Where can I configure this?
Also, tmux didn't use to do this, it started doing it after I updated Ubuntu, from 18.04 onward, and on further clean installations of Ubuntu such as 19.04

Comment: Not a tmux user, but have a look here [How can I make tmux use my default shell?](https://superuser.com/questions/253786/how-can-i-make-tmux-use-my-default-shell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me is configuring tmux so that it uses /bin/bash

To do this, I created the file (which didn't exist) "tmux.conf" in /etc/ and set this single line to it: "set-option -g default-shell /bin/bash", then I restarted the OS.